# From where i can download free control of Ajax Based Grid for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am building a web application in asp.net, does any body know, from where i can download free ajax based standard grid for asp.net having paging and sorting functionality.

Regards
Atif

Comment: Check this link http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/ASPNETAjaxGridAndPager.aspx, it will help you.:)

Answer (score 1):

Obout provides free licenses for students. http://www.obout.com/inc/purchase.aspx. If you're a student, give it a try.

Comment: that's not free, as he ask fee in his question.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: I have stated that it is free for *Students*.

Comment: I have installed these tools, and they are working fine with my code, please let me know, would they be expired after some duration or will keep on working.

Comment: I'm not sure. But based on their site, It's not free for all users. Although, if you're a student, you can get a free license.